# Adding a target to link tags, as long as the href attribute doesn't contain a certain word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I created this function:

```
<?php
    function target_links( $html )
    {       
        $pattern = "/<(a)([^>]+)>/i";
        $replacement = "<\\1 target=\"_blank\"\\2>";
        $new_str = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,str_replace('target="_blank"','',$html));     
        return $new_str;
    }
?>
```

The goal is to add a target="_blank" to all the link tags.

Now my problem is that I need to skip all link tags where the `href` attribute contains a specific word, but I can't seem to find the proper combination. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Is it a must to do this with regex or can you change it to using phps xml functions (DOM*)?

Comment: If the PHP DOM doesn't fail because of broken HTML I'm open for suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not to sure about the "not failing because of broken HTML", but if you can get DomDocument to accept your html, try something like:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml('<html>
    <a href="...protected...">some link</a>
    <a href="...change me...">some link</a>
</html>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[not(contains(@href, "protected"))]') as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this works perfectly - even with missing closing tags. Thank you for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution can look like this:

```
<(a)(?!.*?href="[^"]*SPECIFICWORD)([^>]+)>
```

A negative lookahead `(?!.*?href="[^"]*SPECIFICWORD)` is used to check if the "SPECIFICWORD" is within the href attribute, if yes the regex does not match.

See here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tnu1)